# Can I make div as a background?

Tags: html, css

> Good day, can I make my **div** as a Background?

or how can I set my div at the back of another Div.

Comment: Do some research on css positioning: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Do you have some HTML/CSS code you are currently working with? Post it in your question if you do, otherwise put together an example and people can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You might also want to look at the `z-index` CSS property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use two div tags and give the position as absolute and then give background to one of the div like this :

```
<div class="abc">

</div>
<div class="xyz">
    dgffsgf
</div>
```

and css like :

```
.abc{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.xyz{
    position:absolute;
}
```

This will get your work done!!

Working Code :[Div](http://jsfiddle.net/CHZaT/)

Comment: you should really add some z-indexes to make sure xyz appears on top of abc

Answer (score 3):

the right way to do it is this 4 things:

- width:100%
- height:100%
- position:fixed
- z-index:-1

  .background_div {
      background-color:red;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position:fixed;
      z-index:-1;
   }

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <div class="test"></div>
```

CSS

```
    .test{width:100%;height:100%;background:red;display:block;position:absolute;}
```

Live  Example http://jsfiddle.net/YC6wD/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **really** funky, you could go with the [CSS element()-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/element) (Only working in Firefox). As by the specification:

*Starting in Gecko 2.0, you can use the element() CSS function to use an arbitrary HTML element as a background image for background and background-image*

This simply means that you can use an *actual* `div` (or any other HTML element) to be the `background-image` or another element. [I experimented with this feature before, gave some pretty interesting results](http://www.marcofolio.net/css/experimenting_with_the_element_css_function.html).

(But it isn't that really useful...)